# How can an SSL certificate request be formulated to be granted certifying authority capability?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I know how to create self-signed SSL certificates, but how must  a certificate request be formulated so that the certifying authority grants the certificate the ability to sign certificates?

Let's say I am chief of networks operations in a company. Different IT departments have their own networks they can certify others to connect to, but I have to grant their certificates the ability to sign certificates rather than they creating their own self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the work involved in setting attributes and other pieces of information into a certificate is administrative.

You shouldn't worry much about the certificate request itself. Any decent CA will tear apart the certificate requests it receive to extract the public key and associate it with whatever pieces of information it wants to form the certificate. It should only insert pieces of information that (a) it has been able to verify by some other means (e.g. domain validation, or numerous paper forms, ...) and (b) it's willing to vouch for (and possibly be liable for to a degree, depending on the terms and conditions).

Some well known CAs have schemes to become an intermediate CA. They'll issue you with such a CA certificate. (Hopefully, it's hard to sign up for these schemes...)

If you're deploying your own internal CA and want intermediate CAs, the intermediate CA certificates you issue should have [the `cA` boolean of the basic constraints extension set to true (see RFC 5280)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9). (This is not so much an issue with the certificate requests, but with the certificates you issue.)